# Передача данных GET

Tags: php, ajax

Друзья, столкнулся с такой вот задачей : есть форма, на ней кнопка "оплатить", при нажатии на кнопку, данные о том пользователе который сейчас авторизирован отправляются в файл create.php и там формируются ID заказа и ссылка для оплаты, это все уже работает.
А вот дальше мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "оплатить" - данные отправлялись бы в create.php а открывалась бы сразу та ссылка которая формируется в этом файле с данными которые тоже там формируются.

То есть нажали "оплатить" - данные пошли в create.php, там по этим данным создались orderID и ссылка, дальше эти orderID и ссылка вернулись обратно и уже открылась ссылка с переданным через GET в ней orderID.

Comment: и? где же сам вопрос? В чём проблема, если через тот же AJAX отправить эти данные о пользователе в php файл, там сгенерировать ссылку и через response получить данную ссылку в javascript файле а дальше просто сделать window.location.href= "ваша_ссылка"

Comment: проблема в том, что данные отправляются не через ajax, а просто через submit, а вот получить мне их обратно получается уже нужно через ajax, так как в том php файле есть echo с json_encode

Comment: непонятно, причём тут json_encode? если результат работы php возвращается в json формате, вы так же можете обработать его в javascript-е.  Вот изначально я предлагают отправлять данные не через форму(т.е submit) а отправить данные через ajax, после получить ссылку и сделать редирект. При таком раскладе вам форма не нужна, вы просто сделаете ajax запрос когда пользователь нажмёт на кнопку....

Comment: Проблема в том что код писал не я, и мне нельзя его править и изменять, нужно только дополнить чтобы не затрагивать логику которая сделана

Comment: по сути мне нужно просто понять, как получить правильно вот это echo, и дальше уже вытащить оттуда созданную ссылку и делать на нее переход

Comment: В первую очередь вам надо понять, что вы не сможете получить данные по ajax если делали отправку данных через форму т.е submit......   это разные технологии!!!!  Если ваша задача, это  получить сгенерированную ссылку без перезагрузки страницы, то вам надо все переделать под ajax(отправку и получение данных)

Comment: Хорошо, я понял про разные технологии, а как мне тогда быть, если я захочу и отправлять и принимать данные через AJAX но значения тех переменных которые мне нужно отправлять просто лежат в html полях, могу ли я тогда просто обращаться к значению каждого из полей при отправке данных?

Comment: Для этого советую немножко углубиться в Javascript и у вас будут знания о том, как получить данные из html тегов(input и тд) и тогда, после нажатия пользователем на кнопку, посредством javascript-a вы собираете необходимые данные из html и отправляете через ajax

Comment: а можно ли попробовать сейчас как-то получить данные из php файла, если отправляются они туда через submit?